What is the appropriate VCC to apply to a Schmitt trigger?
I would like to transport a SPI signal over 1 meter, at a 10 MHz clock rate, with each SPI wire twisted with a ground wire, no differential signal, 33 Ohms terminations, ESD protection with chip CM1224-04SO, 26 or 28AWG wires and the entire cable of wires shielded and connected to Earth. The SPI device is a BME680 temperature, pressure and humidity sensor.
To help with signal integrity, I would like to include Schmitt triggers (ref NL27WZ17) on SCK, MOSI and SS on the sensor side and on MISO on my "master" microprocessor's side. My microprocessor has 3.3V logic and is not 5V tolerant.
SPI sensor side:

Master side:


How is the appropriate VCC to apply to Schmitt triggers determined? In my case, is it 3.3V, my maximum logic voltage of my microprocessor?

I also have a doubt whether I interpreted input A and output Y correctly: is A the incoming signal to be rectified, and Y the rectified signal coming out of the Schmitt trigger?

More generally, are my Schmitt triggers correctly implemented?



10MHz SPI can occasionally cause issues just on a PCB - I can't imagine you'll have a great experience along a 1m cable. The crosstalk alone could be an issue.

I’d argue the need for 10MHz SPI to read temperature etc. I hate to say it, I2C might be a better choice as long as your code can tolerate lockups on the bus. Or maybe a small microcontroller  and just talk uart. You have the option of RS485 if you want to go longer distances.

I wish I could go at a lower frequency but I have a recurring timer interrupt happening every 2 ms which lasts 1 ms, and then I only have 1 ms to fetch the environmental data. Environmental data is only collected every 2 seconds. Is there a way to make the SPI transfer happen over several 1ms cycles within the 2 second limit?


If your MCU and sensor both use 3.3V supply for IO, then that's what you use for the Schmitt trigger buffers too.

Yes, the "A" pins 1 and 3 are inputs, the "Y" pins 6 and 4 are outputs.

Now that would depend on what is the intention here. If you are asking if it will work, the Schmitt trigger buffers are likely not an issue here.


There are two issues with cables - they require proper driving circuitry and proper receiving circuitry. This is a 10 MHz bus driven with unknown rise times, but as the signal travels 1 meter in 5ns, any buffer that drives the cable and the 55pF capacitance it has, should be quite strong, and many buffers have faster than 5ns slew rates, so assuming the 1 meter bus is made of twisted pairs like CAT5, it should be considered as transmission line.
The problem is that on the sensor side, you are receiving all input signals through Schmitt triggers. That's fine, but the clock is most important, but the data is hopefully stable already before the active clock edge. Also the SS is important. So yes, it should work. However you have one unused buffer, and the sensor data output is just driven directly. The sensor data output is quite a bit weaker than the buffer output. Since you have an unused buffer, you could buffer the sensor data output to be able to drive the long cable better.
But that might bring another issue - as SPI data outputs are generally tri-stated to be able to connect multiple sensors, that needs to be solved unless you only have one sensor.
Depening on what SPI master you have, it might be beneficial to also buffer the MCU output pins with strong buffers to the 1 meter cable. Especially if there are many sensors on the SPI bus, in addition to the one behind a cable.

Thanks Justme. There is only a single sensor connected via SPI. The reason to connect the MISO line to the buffer on the sensor side is only to strengthen its power, not to rectify it, correct? And likewise on the microprocessor side for the SCK, MOSI and SS? Is this commonly done on all signals going through long cables? Do differential signals, like RS-422 or RS-485, have their drivers take care of that?

@Tommy95 Yes, drivers such as RS-232/422/485 are already intended and designed drive cables. Generally, logic level chips may not be strong enough to drive cables as they are not intended for it. SPI is generally not a bus you wire between two boxes over a 1 meter cable. It's problematic enough to make it work for 30cm on a single PCB.

Thanks! And should termination resistors (33 Ohms in my case) be placed before and after the Schmitt triggers or in between them?

@Tommy95 Usually you put series termination resistors when driving the cable, i.e. they are more useful on outputs than inputs. But driving the cable may not be a problem, but the cable receiving ends seem to be unterminated.

In my diagrams above I put 33 Ohms series termination resistors near the SPI outputs indeed, but now that I included Schmitt triggers, I am wondering if this configuration is correct: "Master" microprocessor SCK pin -> Schmitt trigger -> 33 Ohms termination resistor -> ESD diode -> D-SUB connector pin

Hey Justme, did you mean you would add 120 Ohms resistors from the line to ground on each receiving ends?

@Tommy95 120, 100, or whatever the characteristic impedance of your cable is.
